# How to Remove Strange Ember.js View Margins

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js

Another Ember question: When I started writing my Ember app, I noticed that Ember creates strange, seemingly unremovable margins around the app, that makes my Twitter Bootstrap grid unable to function. I don't quite understand how to get rid of those margins, and how to make columns work again. Here is a picture to show you what I mean:

[image]

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="tasks">
  <div class="well row-fluid span8 offset2 task-list">
    <div class="space-top"><div>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion">
      {{partial 'tasks/newTask'}}
      {{#each task in controller}}
        <div class="accordion-group">
          {{render 'task' task}}
        </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a JSFiddle that doesn't work, but all the code is there: http://jsfiddle.net/SL7s8/

Answer (score 0):

Ember itself doesn't apply any kind of style to your app, but as you can see from the screenshot ember views (by default) render inside a `<div class="ember-view">`. Could be that div is impacting your margins. If that's the case, you can customize it as follows:

```
App.TasksView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: "tasks",
  classNames: ["well", "row-fluid", "span8", "offset2", "task-list"]
});
```

Then change your template to remove the outer div:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="tasks">
<div class="space-top"></div>
<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
  {{partial 'tasks/newTask'}}
  {{#each task in controller}}
    <div class="accordion-group">
      {{render 'task' task}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
</script>
```

UPDATE: Fixed broken `<div class="space-top"><div>` to properly close `</div>` tag

Comment: ok. It's hard to help you without more info. Can you post an example JSFiddle?

Comment: See updated question for the fiddle. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to make it work with the Handlebars templates, but maybe you could help?

Comment: Got the jsfiddle working - it had been referencing a very old version of ember-data, this one uses a recent build: http://jsfiddle.net/mgrassotti/cjtKw/

Comment: how about the question though?

Comment: Running the working jsfiddle linked to above I don't see a problem. The only margins I can see are the ones that bootstrap itself creates, the grid seems to be working perfectly. If that's not the case for you can you post some screenshots of the jsFiddle-version and more detail on specifically what div and what margin is not working?

Comment: just making the changes to your fiddle still doesn't work. When I change the grid to something tiny like `span2` it doesn't make any changes. Here is a forked version of your fiddle with the changes so you can see: http://jsfiddle.net/EguVT/